# Does "topological invariance" of the set of limit points or accumulation points imply the "eventual constantness" of a sequence?

Tags: general-topology

**Problem**

> Let $(X,\tau_0)$ be a topological space with $X(\ne \emptyset)$. Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in X$ and let the set of all adherent points of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in X$ with respect to the toplogy $\tau_0$ be $\mathscr{L}(\tau_0)$. If for any topology (**not the indiscreet and discreet ones**) $\tau$ on $X$ we have $\mathscr{L}(\tau)=\mathscr{L}(\tau_0)$ then prove or disprove that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is ultimately constant. Will your conclusion be same if $\mathscr{L}(\tau)$ would denote the set of all accumulation points?

I have tried to think over the problems for quite sometime but without any progress so far. The almost trivial result that I could prove was if the set $\mathscr{L}(\tau)(\ne \emptyset)$ denotes the set of all limits of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ then the conclusion of the problem holds, i.e., the sequence is ultimately constant.

Can anyone help me in solving the two problems?

---

**Definition of Accumulation Point which I am using:** A point $x\in X$ is said to be an accumulation point of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in X$ if there existis a subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, denoted by $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_{n_k}\ne x$ for all $k$ and it converges to $x$.

**Definition of Adherent Point which I am using:** A point $x\in X$ is said to be an adherent point of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in X$ if there existis a subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, denoted by $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that it converges to $x$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I have changed the links. Please tell me if there is any other problem(s) in the post.

Comment: @user170039: In the interest of clarity, how about you explicitly state the definitions for adherent point and accumulation point you are using (they are unfortunately not entirely standardized terms).

Comment: Why have you made exceptions for the discrete and indiscrete topologies?  This seems like a completely arbitrary choice that will not change the answer to the question in any interesting way but will just make it a bit more complicated to prove.  I also second Justin Benfield's suggestion that you actually write down the definitions you are using yourself, rather than linking to whatever definition you can find on the internet.  Presumably you have gotten this problem from some source, and that source defines the terms it is using.

Comment: @EricWofsey: In answer to your first question, I will say that, actually the problem I proved (briefly mentioned after the question) was assuming those restrictions.

Comment: @JustinBenfield: Thanks for your suggestion. The definitions are now given.

Comment: I think it's ok now. Please see the edit.

Comment: @user170039: You seem to have accidentally given your definition of adherent point for both adherent and accumulation point (note that in the definition of the latter you call it the former).

Comment: @JustinBenfield: Thanks for noting the typo.

Comment: I have started a meta-thread regarding this question [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23758/is-there-any-mathematical-reason-for-which-the-question-was-downvoted). Feel free to comment (or even give an answer).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Have you observed that the link you gave is same as that of mine?

Comment: @EricWofsey: Recently I was reviewing my edits. I wondered what was so vague in my earlier links. The definition of adherent points there was, A point $x$ is an adherent point for $A$ if and only if $x$ is in the closure of $A$. Now take $A=\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and let $x$ to be an Adherent Point of $A$. Then doesn't the definition of the Adherent Point of $A$ (in the just-written sense) turn out to be logically equivalent to the current definition?

Comment: Also regarding the definition of Accumulation Point, I agree that the definition at the link (taken literally) wasn't precise enough. But wasn't it really precise enough? I think that the phrase "[a]n accumulation point is... also called a limit point" is extremely precise because then you know what exactly I am talking about in this context (I assume that the term "limit point" is a standard term).

Comment: @S.D, sorry, somehow your link didn't show up on the machine I was using.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: Consider the set $X=\mathbb{N}$ and two 'near'-indiscrete topologies, $\tau_i$ and $\tau_i^*$. We will arrange that each of them has two nonempty proper subsets, the larger such subsets of $X$, $U_i$ for $\tau_i$, and $U_i^*$ for $\tau_i^*$, chosen so that the given subsets contains all but one natural number; $n_i$ for $\tau_i$ and $n_i^*$ for $\tau_i^*$, furthermore, we will do so, in a way that $n_i\neq n_i^*$, whereas the smaller sets will simply be the complements of of $U_i$ and $U_i^*$ If the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not contain infinitely many copies of either of $n_i$ or $n_i^*$ (note: this means that every subsequence has limit(s), inside both of $U_i$ and $U_i^*$), then we have found topologies such that $\mathscr{L}(\tau)\neq\mathscr{L}(\tau_0)$, for the set of adherent points for $\tau_i$ and $\tau_i^*$ will be $U_i$ and $U_i^*$ respectively. Hence in order to have $\mathscr{L}(\tau_i)=\mathscr{L}(\tau_i^*)$, we need that the sequence contains infinitely many copies of every element, else we can successfully construct the previously described $U_i$ and $U_i^*$ which lead to $\mathscr{L}(\tau)\neq\mathscr{L}(\tau_0)$. Any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which contains infinitely many copies of more than one point cannot be eventually constant because that implies that, after some finite number of terms, all remaining terms are the same point, which is a contradiction (implies every *other* point must occur only finitely many times). Hence, for $X=\mathbb{N}$, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ cannot be ultimately constant.

If we require that the points be *accumulation points* rather than merely adherent points, now we consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ and define 'near'-indiscrete topologies similarly as before. Since, $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, we are guaranteed that we can find, $r_i\neq r_i^*$ (in $\mathbb{R}$) not in $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to use to construct $U_i$ and $U_i^*$ as before. Note that $r_i\in U_i^*$ and $r_i^*\in U_i$. Now in $\tau_i$, since, $\{r_i\}$ is open, we know that $r_i$ is *not* an accumulation point of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ for the topology $\tau_i$. At the same time, we have that $r_i^*$ *is* an accumulation point because it is not in $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ but $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is eventually entirely within every neighborhood of $r_i^*$ (smallest of which is $U_i$). By symmetric arguments, we have that, for the topology $\tau_i^*$, $r_i^*$ is *not* an accumulation point of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ because $\{r_i^*\}$ is open, but also, that $r_i$ *is* an accumulation point of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ because $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is eventually within every neighborhood of $r_i$ (smallest being $U_i^*$). Therefore, we have found topologies for $X=\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathscr{L}(\tau)\neq\mathscr{L}(\tau_0)$. (Hence the conclusion does not change!)

Comment: It seems we have interpreted the questions with different meanings for "adherent point" and "accumulation point".  Unfortunately, the question does not provide a clear definition for either one, linking to a definition of adherent points for sets rather than sequences and a definition of accumulation points that is nonsense.

Comment: Your first statement is false for the definition currently given in the question. Let $X=\beta\Bbb N$, and let $x_n=n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$; no point of $\beta\Bbb N\setminus\Bbb N$ is the limit of a subsequence of $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, though all are in the closure of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: yes, the definition provided at the time I answered was different from the one there now, I am waiting for one more issue to be resolved regarding definitions before revising my answer accordingly.

Comment: @user170039: Corrected answer for the corrected definitions now given.

Comment: Thank you very much for your corrected answer. By the way, I can't actually figure out what was so vague in my earlier definitions (the ones which I linked before any edit). Doesn't they lead us to the same definitions (i.e., the current definitions), as I have noted in the comment thread just below my question?

Comment: @user170039: There is more than one definition of *limit point* in use. Some authors define limit point the same as Accumulation point is here, others define it the same as Adherent point is defined here. So, using a definition that appeals to an (unstated) definition of limit point does not resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: @JustinBenfield: Really? Oh, I didn't know that. But even when you consider both the links then there was probably no question of ambiguity.